# Is there a way to preserve the base Cornerstone theme while updating a custom theme based off of it?

Tags: sass, handlebars.js, bigcommerce

I began theme development based on a modification of the Cornerstone (v1.5.3) theme. Since I initialized my project, I have overridden most of the theme files, including the template handlebars files. If I wanted to implement a "child theme" of Cornerstone, like how the WordPress child theme system works, what procedure would I take to do this? Is it possible? Cornerstone, as of today, has moved to v1.6.3, and I'm unable to update my theme with its changes. If I wanted to inherit from a more up-to-date Cornerstone theme in the future, I couldn't because I've modified the v1.5.3 base files. Is there a way I could update Cornerstone's base so it's not stuck at v1.5.3 for my theme modification forever?

Comment: Are you familiar with using Git via BitBucket or GitHub?

Comment: I'm familiar with GitHub

Comment: You could make your theme into a fork of the cornerstone parent repo and cherry pick upstream commits into yours. I'm not immediately sure of a better way at the development stage you are in.

Comment: I had tried that before I resorted to asking this question, and it was kind of difficult to go through every commit in the main repo and make sure it worked. After that I downloaded the latest Cornerstone base theme and began adding new folders with styles I wanted to override, in the same directory as Cornerstone's css. However, after that I realized that the template files would still have conflicts even though I could sort of modularize the CSS.

Comment: I'm dealing with the same situation and, from what I can tell, this is just a manual, tedious process if you want to keep things in sync with Cornerstone. So far, my conclusion is that it's going to be better long term to develop new themes completely from scratch instead of always watching for Cornerstone bug fixes and features.